# Force Basic Authentication with HttpSendRequest?

Tags: c++, authentication, wininet

Using `InternetSetOption` to set the `username` and `password` when connecting to a `REST` service. I notice that `WinInet` does not send the Authorization header when I call `HttpSentRequest` even though I called InternetSetOption first. Seems ridiculous that you have to get a response from the server with a WWW-Authenication header first. That creates an entire extra request to the server on every request.

Is there a `WinInet` call to force the Authorization header on the first call or do I have to add it manually?

Comment: Have you tried adding the Authentication header directly?

Comment: I ended up adding the Authentication header directly, but it seems like a kludge. Why wouldn't WinInet allow you to specify the Authentication scheme if you already know it?

Comment: I came here looking for an answer to the same puzzle, except I specified the credentials in InternetConnect, not with InternetSetOption. Neither one works as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some deliberation and research, I think the answer is no. To set an Authorization header, WinInet needs to know what authentication method it should use, not just what username and password. The standard way to determine an authentication scheme is to send an unauthenticated request and read the WWW-Authenticate header.

If you *know* that your request needs Basic Authentication, you can set the Authorization: header yourself, using `HttpAddRequestHeaders`:

```
   HttpAddRequestHeaders(hRequest, TEXT("Authentication: Basic dXNlcjpwYXNzd29yZA=="), -1, HTTP_ADDREQ_FLAG_REPLACE);
```

Calculate the base64-encoding of your own "user:password" string using `CryptBinaryToString`.

Answer (score 0):

Call the function InternetSetOptionW before HttpSendRequestW. For example:

```
InternetSetOptionW( hRequest, INTERNET_OPTION_USERNAME, (void*) pwszAuthUserName, wcslen( pwszAuthUserName ) + 1 );
InternetSetOptionW( hRequest, INTERNET_OPTION_PASSWORD, (void*) pwszAuthPassword, wcslen( pwszAuthPassword ) + 1 );
HttpSendRequestW( hRequest, 0, -1, 0, 0 );
```

Comment: The OP says he's already using InternetSetOption, though he's not showing his code. I've tried the same, and still have the same problem: HttpSendRequest sends an initial request without authentication, shortly after followed by an authenticated request.